# saving image via monngoose but cannot find it in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am saving an image via monngoose but I cannot find it in mongodb?

**My Code**

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var app=express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var imgPath = '\Adpic.jpg';

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:/27017/test');

var schema = new Schema({
    img: { data: Buffer, contentType: String }

});

    img: { data: Buffer, contentType: String }

});

var An = mongoose.model('An', schema);
app.post('/upload',function(req,res){    
    var asin = new An();
    asin.img.data = fs.readFileSync(imgPath);
    asin.img.contentType = 'image/jpg';

    asin.save(function (err, a) {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.error('saved img to mongo');
        res.json(a);
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Maybe the [`GridFs`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_gridfs.htm) could be better option to store image into mongodb.

Comment: I fixed you code formating, take on the part where `var schema = new Schema({` and fix the duplication of code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. @Athafoud